# Escaping quotes when isolating strings from input

Tags: python, escaping

I'm trying to parse a file in which quotation files are used to encapsulate strings. For instance, the file might contain a line like this:

```
    "\"Hello there, my friends,\" the tour guide says." me @ swap notify
```

But it might also contain lines like this:

```
    "I'm a dingus who wants to put a backslash at the end of my statements. \\" me @ swap notify
```

In that example, the quotes shouldn't be escaped, but a single backslash should remain.

Is there any function I can use to extract that full quoted statement? \n for newline and \r for carriage return also show up on occasion, so I'd like to get those two, but only after I have the full string isolated.

Comment: Do you no about the [`shlex`](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html) module? It might be useful here.

Comment: @NiklasB. For the specific task the OP posted, `shlex` seems like an overkill...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Parse out the string part. You could use a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) or [string partition](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition)
2. [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) the string and assign it to a variable.

Test:

```
>>> import re
>>> import ast
>>> with open('test.txt.') as f:
...  for line in f:
...   m = re.match('(.*) \w+ @ \w+ \w+', line)
...   print ast.literal_eval(m.group(1))
...
"Hello there, my friends," the tour guide says.
I'm a dingus who wants to put a backslash at the end of my statements. \
```

The regex says "Match anything and store it as *group 1*, up to a space, a word, a space, @-sign, space and a word". You then retreive the group with the `.group(1)` syntax. The parenthesis define a group, see [regex documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group).

Here's a version that tries to parse the string as greedily as possible, by failing and retrying until a match is found, or no match can be made:

```
import re
import ast

def match_line(line):
    while line:
        print "Trying to match:", line
        try:
            return ast.literal_eval(line)
        except SyntaxError, e:
            line = line[:e.offset - 1]
        except ValueError: # No way it would ever match
            break
    return None

with open('test.txt.') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = match_line(line.strip())
        print "Matched:", match
        print
```

Comment: Why mention `eval` at all, seeing that `literal_eval` is so much more appropriate here?

Comment: Also, "parse out the string parse" is actually the hard part (which can be done easily using `shlex`: `shlex.split(s.strip())[0]`). No more `eval`ing involved, then.

Comment: @NiklasB. Because I couldn't *remember* the exact package and function name of `ast.literal_eval` at the time of writing the answer (apparently the very first post cannot be seen in history...). Also, the parsing of the latter part of the line seems trivial with a regex, see updated answer.

Comment: Hey, this seems to work! I'm a little confused on the regex, though. What are those two regexes actually doing?

Comment: Sorry, mistake when pasting. First one is obsolete.

Comment: Oh, wait, I get the regex now. But the end won't always be me @ swap notify.

Comment: Can you define what the ending *can* be?

Comment: The ending can be anything. It may even be nothing. Here's the scenario:

I'm writing a parser for a forth based language. The beginning will always start with a " by the time it gets to this function. Where it ends, I don't know.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8561/discussion-between-kelketek-and-irfy)

Comment: I ended up eventually using this solution instead, only in reverse and with a slightly different structure (since picking an ending slice position out of range does not raise an exception but grabs the rest of the string). That is, I chose to have it match the laziest way. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex. It's usually not recommended for parsing though, because unless you have fairly simple inputs or inputs that follow strict rules, it's easy to make mistakes.
There is probably some sort of parsing module that handles this better (for example the `csv` module is fantastic for quote marks in fields & escaping, if you have a csv).

```
txt1 = r'"\"Hello there, my friends,\" the tour guide says." me @ swap notify.'
txt2 = '"I' + "'" + r'm a dingus who wants to put a backslash at the end of my statements. \\" me @ swap notify'

import re
print re.findall(r'"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)+"',txt1)[0]
# "\"Hello there, my friends,\" the tour guide says."
print re.findall(r'"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)+"',txt2)[0]
# "I'm a dingus who wants to put a backslash at the end of my statements. \\"
```

Note I used the `r'xxxxx'` syntax to avoid having to further escape my backslashes for python (they're already escaped for the regex).

The regex `"([^"\\]|\\.)+"` says "match anything that's not a " or a backslash, OR match a backslash and whatever is immediately following it."

Comment: This one seems to work best for me. The regex makes sense and does what I need it to, and looks like it will work in all cases I have. I'll double check a few things, but this should work.